# @OneToOne unidirectional mapping in JPA2.0 -- getting SQL error on persist

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa-2.0

I can't figure out how to declare a OneToOne unidirectional relationship. The TripDeparture model has the foreign key of the Trip model (that's how the DB is setup). I'm getting the below error when trying to add a trip with departureLocation set to null. When I take out the 'departureLocation' declaration everything works fine.

```
11891 [btpool0-2] WARN org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - SQL Error: 1054, SQLState: 42S22
11891 [btpool0-2] ERROR org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - Unknown column 'tripId' in 'field list'
```

I'm running out of ideas...can anyone help??

Thanks!

The Parent:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TRIP")
public class Trip implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
    @JoinColumn(name = "tripId")
    private TripDeparture departureLocation;
```

The Child:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "DEPARTURE_LOCATION")
public class TripDeparture implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    private int tripId;
```

Comment: Your setup is a bit odd. From the Java perspective the parent knows the child but not the other way round (except for that `tripId` field). On the database level, however, the child (departure) seems to manage the association. Is that intended?

Comment: Yes, that's the intention (for marshalling/unmarshalling reasons, but that's a different conversation).

Comment: Also, this limits me in the way I persist a new Trip (I have to save it with departureLocation being null, and then persist the TripDeparture with the tripId from the saved Trip), but it's intended that way -- I can't have a bidirectional relationship here.

Comment: I think your're missing the @Column annotation on the tripId field.

Comment: @GiorgosDimtsas - the Column annotation isn't required in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how I solved it. Instead of using @JoinColumn I used @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn. I also removed the 'id' variable (and column) in DEPARTURE_LOCATION, but that shouldn't have mattered.

Parent:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TRIP")
public class Trip implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    private TripDeparture departureLocation;
```

Child:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "DEPARTURE_LOCATION")
public class TripDeparture implements Serializable {

    @Id
    private int tripId;
```